# Relativamente às tags de AngularJS

Tags: debate, tags

Dadas as radicais diferenças na versão 2.0 do AngularJS e natural que comecem a aparecer perguntas sobre a mesma. A questão e que AngularJS 1.X vai continuar no activo.

Como devemos proceder em termos de tags? Neste momento temos a tag [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) e a tag [angular2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2). Obliteramos a segunda tag ou deixamos existir? Se deixarmos existir, devemos formaliza-la e chamar-lhe [angularjs2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs2)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google trata as versões, respectivamente, como <kbd>[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)</kbd> e <kbd>[Angular2](https://angular.io/)</kbd>. As tags no SO original seguem o mesmo padrão. Acho que deveríamos mantê-los.

Comment: Isso deve ter sido pressão da Microsoft por causa do TypeScript :)

Comment: Boa, você me fez riscar minha resposta.

Comment: O OCD em mim fica com tiques nervosos com esse AngularJS/Angular2 :P

Comment: @Omni vou te confessar que sinto o mesmo. Mas as duas tecnologias são tão diferentes que trato como se fossem coisas não relacionadas.

Answer (score 2):

Ignorem essa resposta, a resposta dada pelo [@lbotinelly](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1897/lbotinelly) faz mais sentido.

<s>Sou contra a existência da tag [angular2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2), na minha opinião deveríamos utilizar a tag [angularjs-2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2) com o traço separando o nome do *framework* da sua versão.</s>

Também podemos aproveitar o fato de ainda não haver muitas perguntas com essa tag (duas no momento da escrita dessa resposta) e já edita-las, antes que outros usuários venham a utiliza-la em suas perguntas.

Comment: Podemos criar `angularjs-2` e `angularjs-1.x`, com `angularjs` como sinônimo mapeando para `angularjs-1.x`. Mais adiante provavelmente fará sentido mudar esse mapeamento pra tag da versão 2.

Comment: Legal @bfavaretto, não sabia que era possível assim tão facilmente.

Comment: Mais ou menos "facilmente"... :-D

Comment: Hehehehe saquei xD

Comment: @Zignd acho que devias manter a tua resposta como estava, para que possam votar nela, ou não. Mas é importante ter as duas opções para votar, se quiseres pordes por como wiki de comunidade.